# input text field on javascript radio click

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have three radio buttons

```
   <input type="radio" name="selection" class="selection" data-id='0' value="search" checked="checked" />Search for a client
    <input type="radio" name="selection" class="selection" data-id='0' value="sel" />Mass E-mail
    <input type="radio" name="selection" class="selection" data-id='0' value="others" onclick="getElementById('other').style.display = null;" />Other E-mail
```

on select I need to change the text fields and get different text fields on different selects.

Here is my function

```
$('.selection').live('click',function(){
        var id =  $(this).attr('data-id');
        if(id == 0){id='';}
        var selectedVal = $(this).val();
        if(selectedVal=='sel'){
            $('#customer_search_query'+id).attr('style','display:none');
            $('#customers_email_address'+id).attr('style','display:inline');
            $('#customer_id'+id).val('');
            $('#customer_search_query'+id).val('');
            $('#customers_email_address'+id).val('');
             $('#other'+id).attr('style','display:none');
        }else if(selectedVal=='search'){
            $('#customer_search_query'+id).attr('style','display:inline');
            $('#customers_email_address'+id).attr('style','display:none');
            $('#customer_id'+id).val('');
            $('#customer_search_query'+id).val('');
            $('#customers_email_address'+id).val('');
             $('#other'+id).attr('style','display:none');
        }
        else {
            $('#customer_search_query'+id).attr('style','display:none');
            $('#customers_email_address'+id).attr('style','display:none');
            $('#other'+id).attr('style','display:inline');
        }
    });
```

The problem, on first two radio buttons, it is working perfectly but on third click I need simple text field and it is not working.  This is existing script on this system. 
Please let me know if I missed any thing.

Comment: What version of jQuery are you using? `.live()` was deprecated in 1.7, removed in 1.9. You should be using `.on()` unless you're stuck with a really old version.

Comment: I am working on some old version because this project is in oscommerce and after adding new version, some of its functionality stops so i have to work on previous version.

Comment: You should use `.hide()` and `.show()` instead of setting the `style` attribute. And when you want to set styles, you should use `.css()`, not `.attr()`.

Comment: Show the HTML of the form fields.

Comment: You need to remove the property onclick="getElementById('other').style.display = null;" from the third input control

Answer (score 0):

> You need to remove the onclick event from the third control to go
>   through the jQuery function (onclick="document.getElementById('other').style.display = null;"):

```js
$('.selection').live('click', function() {
  var id = $(this).attr('data-id');
  if (id == 0) {
    id = '';
  }
  var selectedVal = $(this).val();
  if (selectedVal == 'sel') {
    $('#customer_search_query' + id).attr('style', 'display:none');
    $('#customers_email_address' + id).attr('style', 'display:inline');
    $('#customer_id' + id).val('');
    $('#customer_search_query' + id).val('');
    $('#customers_email_address' + id).val('');
    $('#other' + id).attr('style', 'display:none');
  } else if (selectedVal == 'search') {
    $('#customer_search_query' + id).attr('style', 'display:inline');
    $('#customers_email_address' + id).attr('style', 'display:none');
    $('#customer_id' + id).val('');
    $('#customer_search_query' + id).val('');
    $('#customers_email_address' + id).val('');
    $('#other' + id).attr('style', 'display:none');
  } else {
    $('#customer_search_query' + id).attr('style', 'display:none');
    $('#customers_email_address' + id).attr('style', 'display:none');
    $('#other' + id).attr('style', 'display:inline');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="radio" name="selection" class="selection" data-id='0' value="search" checked="checked" />Search for a client
<input type="radio" name="selection" class="selection" data-id='0' value="sel" />Mass E-mail
<input type="radio" name="selection" class="selection" data-id='0' id="other" value="others" />Other E-mail
```

Comment: @AftabHafeez please check this is what you want to achieve??

Comment: @AftabHafeez I modified the code now when you click on the third radio button the radio button is hide

Comment: third radio button is not working... please edit it thanks

Comment: Can you tell me the behavior that you want when click each one of the radio buttons, because now when you click the first or second the third radio button is hide